# Strange dissapearing input box in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I have found a really strange issue with my ionic form, basically I have a single input that is no different from any of the others but if the content is longer than the input box, it seems to disappear but appear with a few actions (see GIF)

[image]

Has anyone seen this before?

Code which powers the forms,

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content class="padding" style="padding-top: 0px;" scroll="true" has-bouncing="true">
        <ion-refresher class="primary-color" pulling-text="Refresh" on-refresh="vm.update();" spinner="none">
        </ion-refresher>
        <div class="group-list list list-inset" style="padding: 14x;">
            <label ng-repeat="field in vm.model.Fields | filter: vm.fieldFilter" class="item item-input editor-field">
                <span class="input-label font-thin">{{field.Name}}</span>

                <input  type="text" class="primary-color" placeholder="{{field.Editor === 'readonly' ? 'Readonly' : 'Update'}}"
                       ng-class="{readonly: field.Editor === 'readonly'}"
                       ng-model="field.Value"
                       ng-click="vm.editorFor(field)"
                       ng-disabled="field.Editor === 'readonly'"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Without code we really can't help. We'd need to *see* this problem occuring to diagnose.